# Where is the template for try-catch blocks stored?

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-8

Does anyone know where the code template for try-catch blocks is stored in Netbeans settings? The specific template I'm referring to is inserted when I type `try {` and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After I do that, the following code block appears:

```
try {

} catch (Exception $ex) {

}
```

I would like to insert a newline between the try block and the `catch` statement but I don't know how to change this. I tried going to `Tools->Options->Editor->Code Templates` but I couldn't find whatever causes the above block to expand.

Answer (score 2):

With *Tools->Options->Editor->Code Templates* you are on the right way look up in the first column of the table the *Abbreviation*: *trycatch* then youll see bellow the editable template and do it as I show you, dont forget to apply chages:

```
try {
"new line" // this line here I have put it
${selection}${cursor}
} ${CATCH_STMTS uncaughtExceptionCatchStatements default="catch (Exception e) {}" editable=false}
```

I have test it on NetBeans IDE 8.1 RC2 (Build 201510122201) and after writing trycatch and press tab it generates:

```
try {
                "new line"

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
```

I hope it helps!!!!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see `trycatch`. I see `tryf` and `tryc` but they don't affect the block I am trying to change. I should note I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 so maybe this has been changed in 8.2